# Css3 Translate on child element doesn't work

Tags: css, css-transforms

Here is my css:

```
#sort_dropdown:hover > .arrow{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    transform: translate(0,-42px);

}
```

here is my code:

```
<li><a id="sort_dropdown">Sortieren <span class="arrow">&darr;</span><span class="arrow" style="display: none;">&uarr;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Transforms only work on elements with block-level display. Setting `.arrow` to `display: inline-block` (spans display `inline` by default) does the trick ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/yT8Lc/)):

```
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I found that transforms work with `display:flex` too ...and that's when I became aware that [flex is block-level (unless inline-flex)](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/does-display-flex-change-block-elements-to-be-inline-elements).